# Rails - MS-SQL Server problems (unixODBC, FreeTDS) on Mac 10.6

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, macos, odbc

Followed the instructions on the Rails wiki and have had success connecting to SQL Server 2000 with TSQL -- both with DSN-less and DNS connections. I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.3.

[Wiki instructions here.](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/ms-sql)

Installed ruby-odbc, dbi (0.4.0), dbd-odbc (2.4.5), activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (2.3.5).

In my database.yml (Rails 2.3.6):

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: ODBC
  dsn: 'DRIVER=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so;TDS_Version=8.0;SERVER=mssql01.discountasp.net;DATABASE=DB_164368_dmusd;Port=1433;uid=DB_164368_dmusd_user;pwd=Schools77;'
```

This yields the following error: **ODBC::Error: S1090 (0) [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Invalid string or buffer length**

When I attempt to use a DSN connection, I get the following error: **ODBC::Error: IM002 (0) [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified**

I have in fact verified that the FreeTDS driver (libtdsodbc.so) is installed and the path correct.

Can anyone spot the error of my ways? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the configuration between:

```
freetds.conf

[somesqlserver]
 host = HOST_ADDRESS
 port = 1433
 tds version = 8.0 # for SQL2000
```

and

```
odbc.ini

[server_connection]
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Server = ip_address_of_server
Database = database_name
client charset = UTF-8  #needed only on osx
```

in database.yml

```
development:
adapter: sqlserver
mode: odbc
dsn: server_connection
username: your_username
password: your_password
```

[Very good article for reference on osx but easily adaptable to unix](http://toolmantim.com/thoughts/getting_rails_talking_to_sqlserver_on_osx_via_odbc)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial to connect your rails app to MS SQL Server

Connect To MicrosoftSQLServer From Rails On Linux Box:
http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/ms-sql

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise that you forget UnixODBC on Mac OS X.  Instead, update the iODBC components to [the latest version](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X).

iODBC -- the open source ODBC driver manager Apple chose to ship with Mac OS X -- comes from the same source as the open source [ODBC Adapter for Ruby on Rails](http://odbc-rails.rubyforge.org/) -- [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/).

It may also be worth your while to test, if not deploy, with a commercial ODBC driver, such as [that from OpenLink](http://download.openlinksw.com/solwiz/view_solution.php?solutions_id=2536&solution_num=1).  This can help narrow down the source of errors you encounter when trying to use a "no cost" driver.  (There's always a cost -- the only question is whether you spend money or time.)

ObDisclaimer: I work for OpenLink Software, but do not directly benefit from anyone choosing to use our products.

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation when recommending commercial products produced by your employer.